# Angular $broadcast issue

Tags: angularjs, broadcast

Let's say I have two pages, page A and page B, which have controller A and controller B, respectively. I go to page A first, and do an operation, which would call $broadcast to send out one object:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('payData', obj)
```

I want to receive this broadcast in controller B. But since I have not gone to page B, the constructor of controller B is not initialized. Since I try to receive this message in the constructor of controller B, it never receives the message.

```
export default class ControllerB{
    constructor($scope, $rootScope){
        this.scope = $scope;
        this.rootScope = $rootScope

        $rootScope.$on('payData', (event, obj) => {
            console.log('broadcastPayData receive obj:', obj);
        })
    }
    //some other cool staff
}
```

Any idea how to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: You should store the `payData` in a service. Using events won't work if the controllers aren't going to be active at the same time (and they're generally very fragile anyway).

Comment: @JoeClay, smart, good idea! thanks

Answer (score 0):

If controller B doesn't exist yet, it would make sense to just save the object to rootScope and B will access it once it's loaded:

```
$rootScope.payData = obj
```

Then just use it in your controllerB

```
export default class ControllerB{
    constructor($scope, $rootScope){
        this.scope = $scope;
        this.rootScope = $rootScope

        console.log($rootScope.payData);
    }
    //some other cool staff
}
```

You can also watch the `$rootScope.payData` if it can change over time.

Comment: Using `$rootScope` to share data between controllers tends to be pretty unmaintainable in the long run. This is why Angular has services - to contain logic/data that should be shared around the application.

Comment: @JoeClay Sure, using a service is a great idea